# React-Hook-Form useForm is not a function

Tags: react-hook-form, next.js14

I am using NextJs 14 and React Hook Form and I keep running in this [image: error]

I used the guide from the official docs and nothing worked.

I have tried uninstall react hook from and reinstalling it, also attempted to delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`

```
export default function Home() {

  const {

    register,

    formState: { errors },

  } = useForm<FormData>({

    resolver: zodResolver(UserSchema), // Apply the zodResolver

  });

  return (

      <form onSubmit={() => {}}>

        <div className="grid col-auto">

          <FormField

            type="email"

            placeholder="Email"

            name="email"

            register={register}

            error={errors.email}

          />

          <button type="submit">

            Submit email

          </button>

        </div>

      </form>

  );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"use client"` at the very top of your component.

```
"use client"

export default function Home() {

  const {

    register,

    formState: { errors },

  } = useForm<FormData>({

    resolver: zodResolver(UserSchema), // Apply the zodResolver

  });

  return (

      <form onSubmit={() => {}}>

        <div className="grid col-auto">

          <FormField

            type="email"

            placeholder="Email"

            name="email"

            register={register}

            error={errors.email}

          />

          <button type="submit">

            Submit email

          </button>

        </div>

      </form>

  );

};

``
```